# How would I calculate the area of the shaded region of a circle with radius $6$ and length of chord $AB=6. $

Tags: geometry, circles

How would I calculate the area of the shaded region of a circle with radius 6 and length of chord AB is 6.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to find the area of an equilateral triangle and a circular sector?

Comment: Area of sector = area of shaded region + area of equilateral triangle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Join the center of the circle to the points A and B. You'll obtain a triangle. What type of triangle is it?

Comment: I get it :  
Area of sector = area of shaded region + area of equilateral triangle

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be center of given circle. From assumption you have $\bar{OA}=\bar{OB}=6$. So you have  all information to find: (a) area of triangle $ABO$ (b) angle between $\bar{OA}$ and $\bar{OB}$. Next use formula for area of fragment of a circle between points $A, B$ and $O$ say - P. Finally subtract area of area of the triangle $ABO$ from P and get the result.