# What is the area inside the curves $r = \cos\theta$ and $r = \sin\theta$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, polar-coordinates

I have set up an integral's bounds in polar coordinates: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\sin\theta}^{\cos\theta}drd\theta$, but I do not know what function to integrate (what goes inside the integral symbols). I included an image of my thought process of how I approached this problem setup. [image: area under curves diagram]

Comment: The "function to integrate" to get an area is just $1$. Your integral is wrong in terms of the limits, see Doug M.'s answer, and you also need a factor of $r$ when you integrate with polar coordinates.

Comment: It may help you - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171937/area-between-polar-equation-r-sin-theta-and-r-cos-theta

Comment: @SuzuHirose Got it, thank you for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the area between the two circles it must be that

$r\le \min(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$

or, $r \le\begin{cases}\sin \theta& 0\le \theta\le \frac \pi4\\\cos \theta & \frac \pi4<\theta\le \frac \pi 2\end{cases}$

The region is symmetric across the line $\theta = \frac \pi4$ So, we can integrate from $0$ to $\frac \pi4$ and double the result.

$2\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{4}}\int_0^{\sin\theta} r\ dr\ d\theta\\
2\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{4}} \frac 12 r^2 |_0^{\sin \theta}\ d\theta\\
\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{4}}  \sin^2\theta\ d\theta$

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the "function to integrate" is $1$ when computing the area.

Comment: @SuzuHirose The function to integrate is $r$ when working in polar coordinates.  That is the Jacobian associated with the coordinate system.

Comment: That's the jacobian but the function which is integrated is 1. The jacobian is the same regardless of function so I don't think that is at all the "function to integrate". The OP was asking about "what function to integrate to get the area".